# How do we find the range of $z^z, \: z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

I was recently exploring domain colouring, when the transformation $z \mapsto z^z$ changed the complex plane thus:

[image: Untransformed]

[image: Transformed]

This made me wonder how we could mathematically describe the coloured 'boomerang' region, which represents the range of the function $z^z$ (the white areas have no values at their corresponding points). Of course, one way to describe the region would be,

$S = \{ \left(x, y \right) : \left(x, y \right) \in \mathbb{R}^2,  x+iy = z^z, z \in \mathbb{C} \}$

Which corresponds to the range $\{ z : z \in \mathbb{C}, z = w^w, w \in \mathbb{C} \}$

But is there any way of finding the range in another form?

Comment: Erm... $\{ z : z \in \mathbb{C}, z = w^w, w \in \mathbb{C} \}$ *is* a parametric form, isn't it?

Comment: I meant any *other* parametric form :)

Comment: Is this diagram saying $z^z$ can't be $i$? [It can](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+z%5Ez%3Di).

Comment: @J.G. No, a small part of the imaginary axis, on either side of the origin, has some colour (albeit they're fainter than in the rest of the complex plane)

Comment: What function determines the colour coordinates? Your real question may be which values are at least as colourful as some cutoff, which is a lot less trivial.

Comment: The colour coordinates represent the argument of the complex number. The application is designed such that no possible argument can assume the colours white or black.

Answer (score 1):

If $z=\exp W(\ln w)$ with $W$ a branch of the Lambert-$W$ function,$$z^z=\exp(z\ln z)=\exp(\ln w)=w.$$This works for all $w\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.